# How to unpack Array to Rows in Snowflake?

Tags: sql, arrays, json, list, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table that looks like the following in Snowflake:

```
ID | CODES
2  | [ { "list": [ { "item": "CODE1" }, { "item": "CODE2" } ] } ]
```

And I want to make it into:

```
ID | CODES
2  | 'CODE1'
2  | 'CODE2'
```

So far I've tried

```
SELECT ID,CODES[0]:list
FROM MY_TABLE
```

But that only gets me as far as:

```
ID | CODES
2  | [ { "item": "CODE1" }, { "item": "CODE2" } ]
```

How can I break out every 'item' element from every index of this list into its own row with each CODE as a string?

**Update**: Here is the answer I got working at the same time as the answer below, looks like we both used FLATTEN:

```
SELECT ID,f.value:item
FROM MY_TABLE,
lateral flatten(input => MY_TABLE.CODES[0]:list) f
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as you note you have hard coded your access into the codes, via `codes[0]` which gives you the first item from that array, if you use FLATTEN you can access all of the objects of the first array.

```
WITH my_table(id,codes) AS (
  SELECT 2, parse_json('[ { "list": [ { "item": "CODE1" }, { "item": "CODE2" } ] } ]')
)
SELECT ID, c.*
FROM my_table,
    table(flatten(codes)) c;
```

gives:

```
2   1       [0] 0   { "list": [ { "item": "CODE1" }, { "item": "CODE2" }]}  [    {      "list": [{"item": "CODE1"}, { "item": "CODE2" }]}]
```

so now you want to loop across the items in `list`, so we use another FLATTEN on that:

```
WITH my_table(id,codes) AS (
  SELECT 2, parse_json('[ { "list": [ { "item": "CODE1" }, { "item": "CODE2" } ] } ]')
)
SELECT ID, c.value, l.value
FROM my_table,
    table(flatten(codes)) c,
    table(flatten(c.value:list)) l;
```

gives:

```
2   {"list":[{"item": "CODE1"},{"item":"CODE2"}]}   {"item":"CODE1"}
2   {"list":[{"item": "CODE1"},{"item":"CODE2"}]}   {"item":"CODE2"}
```

so you can pull apart that `l.value` how you need to access the parts you need.